# Cannot remove mount option "discard" on an ext4 file system

Tags: linux, filesystems, ssd, ext4, trim

I tried to turn off TRIM (*"discard"*) on my `ext4` filesystem, but I did not succeed.

I tried to add `nodiscard` option into `/etc/fstab`, but I can still see this:

```
# tune2fs -l /dev/md2 | grep discard
Default mount options:    journal_data_writeback user_xattr acl discard
```

OS is GNU/Debian, and the disk is an SSD.

Comment: Why do you think modifying the fstab would change the default mount options that stored in the filesystem metadata?  Changing the fstab options will only change the options used at mount time.

Comment: Well, because I couldn't find any better ideas to try. I looked on the internet on ways to set the fs to "nodiscard" but I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the command to remove "discard" is this
`tune2fs -o^discard /dev/md2`